# Trying to send a batch of SMS from a sybase database

Tags: php

PHP Warning:  sybase_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/smsproject/directcreditsms.php on line 40

```
$q=sybase_query("select itbid from phoenix..itranlog3 a where postdate=$strdate and itbid not in (select batch_id from phoenix..sms_batch_alert_control where batch_id=a.itbid)");
        $numrows = sybase_num_rows($q);
        //echo "number of rows returned is : " . $numrows . "\n";
        $batchids="";
if($numrows >= 1)
{

                while($row = sybase_fetch_assoc($q))
                {
                        $batch_id[]=$row['itbid'];
                }
```

Comment: Is there an extra period there: `phoenix..itranlog3`? I'm not familiar with this exact method but I think it would return a boolean false if the query fails.

Comment: Would `$strdate` need to be quoted? I know it does in mysql, but I'm not familiar with sybase

Comment: @yaakov the double periods are okay. They seem to be working well with the directdebitsms.php file

Comment: The itranlog3 was wrong